# Низкая скорость работы Windows 7 в виртуальной машине VirtualBox при работе с флэшки

Tags: windows, virtualbox

Всем доброго времени суток!

- Рабочий компьютер: Процессор AMD A8-5600K 3.60GHz, ОЗУ 12Gb 1600MHz,
  ОС Windows 7x64, антивирус 360 Total Security (файл виртуального
  диска добавлен в доверенные), защитник Windows выключен.
- Носитель: USB (3.1) Flash Kingston HyperX Savage HXS3 64Гб
- Виртуальная машина: VirtualBox 5.1.2 r108956 (Extension Pack 5.1.2r108956)
- Настройки виртуальной машины: 2 процессора, 4096Гб ОЗУ, 256Мб
  видеопамяти, 2D и 3D ускорение видео включено, аппаратная виртуализация включена, контроллер носителя SATA(AHCI)
- Целевая ОС: Windows 7x64

**Столкнулся со следующей проблемой**: создал виртуальный диск VHD для работы Windows 7 на съемном носителе. Процесс установки занимает примерно 30 минут. После копирования и распаковки системы на флэшку скорость падает почти до нуля. Каждое действие занимает минут по пять! Работать в такой среде практически невозможно. Носитель на рабочем компьютере определяется как "Съемное устройство". HD Tune Pro показывает скорость чтения файла 300Мб\с, записи файла - 200Мб\с.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем может быть проблема? На форумах и в различных статьях пишут, что скорость работы даже на USB 2.0 терпимая.

Comment: Виртуальный диск у вас динамический или фиксированный? Если динамический, переделайте на фиксированный.

Comment: Я так понимаю ты сделал что-то типа `windows 10 to go`, но на 7? Если так, то чем создавал VHD? Если средствами VB, то в интернете советуют делать средставми самой винды - различия есть.

Comment: VHD-диск фиксированный. Создавал средствами VirtualBox.

Answer (score 1):

Всем спасибо! Нашел решение проблемы. Достаточным оказалось активировать кэширование флэшки на рабочем компьютере (Управление компьютером->Управление дисками->Правый клик на диске в нижней части окна->Свойства, вкладка "Политика", "Разрешить кэширование записей для этого устройства") и включить кэширование ввода/вывода в контроллере SATA виртуальной машины. Также сменил файловую систему на самом носителе на exFat, но думаю, что это не особо повлияло на результат.